# Cannot access object's properties - objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot of mine and I was making a "help" command. I first had a commands array and if they wanted help on a specific command I had to add more lines of code than I want to. I was wondering if I could do put an object inside of my object like this:

```
const commands1 = {
    coinflip: {
        usage: prefix + "coinflip",
        description: `Flip a coin then guess what it landed on.`
    }
    diceroll: {
        usage: prefix + "diceroll (number)",
        description: `Roll a die and guess what it lands on`
    }
};
```

Or would I have to do something else, because when I do

```
for(var name in commands1){
    embed.addField("Command:", name)
}
```

this will list all the commands available. However I can't access the usage or description, I tried this by doing this:

```
.addField("Usage:", name.usage)
.addField("Description:", name.description)
```

(it says undefined) Am I accessing it wrong or can I not put objects in objects. Sorry, I'm relatively new to this :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that name. is literal and it thinks I'm trying to access commands1.name when I wanted commands1.coinflip. So I fixed it by doing this

```
console.log(commands1.coinflip.usage)
```

Comment: If you are hard coding coinflip either way you should use dot notation. If you are passing it in as a variable (e.g. `name`) then you can get get by with lookup syntax (e.g. commands1[name].usage)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `for...in` loop, which iterates over the indexes of the array. But the real scenario is you have `object`. So, in this case i would suggest you this:

```js
const commands1 = {
    coinflip: {
        usage: prefix + "coinflip",
        description: `Flip a coin then guess what it landed on.`
    }
    diceroll: {
        usage: prefix + "diceroll (number)",
        description: `Roll a die and guess what it lands on`
    }
};

const keys = Object.keys(commands1); // #Output : ["coinflip", "diceroll"]

for(let key of keys){
   embed.addField("Command:", commands1[key].usage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine with what I have, I only use the for loop to look at commands names so it can list all the commands. The part that I have that looks for the specific command they entered is just `commands1[commandname].usage` and it works like a charm, I eliminated quite a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about being new, we all started somewhere.

Your newbie questions are probably better than mine were!

```
const commands1 = {
    coinflip: {
        usage: prefix + "coinflip",
        description: `Flip a coin then guess what it landed on.`
    },
/* Added a missing , above */ 
    diceroll: {
        usage: prefix + "diceroll (number)",
        description: `Roll a die and guess what it lands on`
    }
};

for(var name in commands1){
    embed.addField("Command:", name);
    console.log(commands1[name].usage);
    console.log(commands1[name].description); /* You can Use your index to directly access the object thru the parent object. */ 
}
```

Comment: FYI: My answer looks the same as above Jai's ... but, a little easier on the resources + better performance.  I'm not placing unnecessary data in memory (Eg: keys.)

While for this trivial example ... either solution works great - when the solution scales ... less is more.